# Parsing json in python

Tags: python, json, logstash

I am having trouble parsing the following json file. I am trying to parse this using logstash/python.

```
{
  "took" : 153,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 946,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "incoming_bytes",
      "_type" : "logs",
      "_id" : "lZSq4mBRSVSxO0kyTwh3fQ",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {"user_id":"86c8c25d81a448c49e3d3924ea5ceddf","name":"network.incoming.bytes","resource_id":"instance-00000001-c8be5ca1-116b-45b3-accb-1b40050abc90-tapaf1e421f-c8","timestamp":"2013-11-02T07:32:36Z","resource_metadata":{"name":"tapaf1e421f-c8","parameters":{},"fref":null,"instance_id":"c8be5ca1-116b-45b3-accb-1b40050abc90","instance_type":"5c014e54-ee16-43a8-a763-54e243bd8969","mac":"fa:16:3e:67:39:29"},"volume":557462,"source":"openstack","project_id":"9ac587404bdd4fcdafe41c0b10f9f8ae","type":"cumulative","id":"f1eb19aa-4390-11e3-8bac-000c2973cfb1","unit":"B","@timestamp":"2013-11-02T07:32:38.276Z","@version":"1","host":"127.0.0.1","tags":["_grokparsefailure"],"priority":13,"severity":5,"facility":1,"facility_label":"user-level","severity_label":"Notice","@type":"%{appdeliveryserver}"}
    }, {
      "_index" : "incoming_bytes",
      "_type" : "logs",
      "_id" : "073URWt5Sc-krLACxQnI3g",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {"user_id":"86c8c25d81a448c49e3d3924ea5ceddf","name":"network.incoming.bytes","resource_id":"instance-00000001-c8be5ca1-116b-45b3-accb-1b40050abc90-tapaf1e421f-c8","timestamp":"2013-11-02T07:32:38Z","resource_metadata":{"name":"tapaf1e421f-c8","parameters":{},"fref":null,"instance_id":"c8be5ca1-116b-45b3-accb-1b40050abc90","instance_type":"5c014e54-ee16-43a8-a763-54e243bd8969","mac":"fa:16:3e:67:39:29"},"volume":562559,"source":"openstack","project_id":"9ac587404bdd4fcdafe41c0b10f9f8ae","type":"cumulative","id":"f31e38d4-4390-11e3-8bac-000c2973cfb1","unit":"B","@timestamp":"2013-11-02T07:32:39.001Z","@version":"1","host":"127.0.0.1","tags":["_grokparsefailure"],"priority":13,"severity":5,"facility":1,"facility_label":"user-level","severity_label":"Notice","@type":"%{appdeliveryserver}"}
    }]
  }
}
```

I have used the following configuration for logstash, however the configuration does not work as expected which is: to parse individual fields in the JSON document and output to STDOUT.

```
input {
 stdin{}
  file {

        path => ["/home/****/Downloads/throughput"]
        codec => "json"
    }
}
filter{
    json{

        source => "message"
        target => "throughput"

    }
}
output {
  stdout {codec => rubydebug }

}
```

For python I am trying to access the Individual Volume and  source (IP address) fields.

I tried the following code, with goal to map individual fields for each record, and I would like to know how to proceed in order to traverse and extract individual elements in the list.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

json_data=open('throughput')

data = json.load(json_data)

pprint(data["hits"])

json_data.close()
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your exact problem? I.e. what is not working and what way?

Comment: Logstash: Logstash does not provide any output to stdout, I checked the json validator and the format is valid. Python: I would like to know how to proceed to traverse and extract individual fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsed json is a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=dictionary#dictionaries), you can use [itemgetter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to drill down.

For example for volume

```
>>> for hits in data['hits']['hits']:
...     print hits['_source']['volume']
...
557462
562559
```

or can use [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to get a list:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> map(itemgetter('volume'), map(itemgetter('_source'), data['hits']['hits']))
[557462, 562559]
```

Comment: Thanks, got it working yesterday itself. As it works, i also have thoughts regarding the failure in Logstash. Any comments?